# How to make editable table using bootstrap and jQuery only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This is my bootstrap table.I want to insert data into table using jQuery only.On clicking a particular cell,a textbox should be open to enter data.I don't want to use any other plugin.

```
       <table class="table table-bordered">
         <thead class="mbhead">
           <tr class="mbrow">
             <th>A</th>
             <th>B</th>
             <th>C</th>
             <th>D</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
             <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>          
         </tbody>
       </table>
```

help me.thanx.

Comment: You must be having any database for this?

Comment: Right now,i am not thinking about database..just make it editable only

Comment: this might be helpful http://jsfiddle.net/JPVUk/1/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You basically want to add an event to the user clicking on a table row. In jQuery you can add that event like this

```
$("table.table tr td").bind("click", dataClick);
```

In the dataClick function you wan to make the row editable. You can do so like this.

```
function dataClick(e) {
    console.log(e);
    if (e.currentTarget.innerHTML != "") return;
    if(e.currentTarget.contentEditable != null){
        $(e.currentTarget).attr("contentEditable",true);
    }
    else{
        $(e.currentTarget).append("<input type='text'>");
    }    
}
```

I have a sample here, http://jsfiddle.net/JPVUk/4/

Hope this helps

Comment: @Amrendra Try using `live()` instead of `bind()`. Like this, http://jsfiddle.net/JPVUk/5/

Comment: live() was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in 1.9.  You can put it back with the jQuery migrate plugin but I'm not so sure that's a good idea going forward.